# How to declare an array of objects in F#?

Tags: .net, f#

I have this declaration of an array in C#:

```
object[] objects = { "myString", 12, 2.06, null, "otherString" };
```

Now I want to declare a similar array in F#, so I try:

```
let objects = ["myString"; 12; 2.06; null; "otherString"]
```

But this gives me compile errors:

*"This expression was expected to have type string but here has type int"*

and

*"This expression was expected to have type string but here has type float"*

for values 12 and 2.06.

How should I proceed to create a similar array in F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code you are declaring a list:

```
let objects : obj list = ["myString"; 12; 2.06; null; "otherString"]
```

an array would be:

```
let objects : obj[] = [|"myString"; 12; 2.06; null; "otherString"|]
```

just add a type annotation `:obj list` or `: obj[]` to any of those, otherwise F# infers the type from the first element.

Comment: Also note that this is not an array, but a list. Array is denoted with "bracket-pipe": `[| 1; 2; 3 |]`

Comment: @FyodorSoikin true, but for array `: obj []` annotation is also needed `let objects : obj[] = [|"myString"; 12; 2.06; null; "otherString"|]`